# How to create custom scope and share same instances using Dagger Android

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

So here are the things I know from the [doc](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents)

1. Dagger Android under the hood is creating subcomponent for each Activity annotated with `ContributesAndroidInjector`
2. You can apply custom scope to the method where `ContributesAndroidInjector` is annotated to
3. **If two sibling subcomponents have the same scope, they will still have different scope instances**
4. If an Activity is in a subcomponent, it can have its own subcomponent which can contain Fragments. Those Fragments will share the scoped instances the Activity has.

Now my question is:
How to have one Activity be a subcomponent of another activity using Dagger Android?

I want to do this because I want to achieve things like @UserScope/@SessionScope.

From [this](http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/) I know that I can do it with just Dagger not Dagger Android. But with Dagger Android, you can only have the Application (which is the AndroidInjector) to inject Activity. You can not have an Activity used as a holder or host of the parent subcomponent to inject another Activity.

Am I understanding it correctly?

**05/14/2018 Update:**

I ended up getting rid of Dagger Android. So no more `ContributesAndroidInjector`, just pure Dagger. And to inject Activity/Fragment, I use the way that's recommended [here](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/that-missing-guide-how-to-use-dagger2-ef116fbea97). It will be something like this:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = Injector.myCustomScope().factory()
}
```

And we are trying to make sure the factory is the only thing that Activity/Fragment needs.

So far it's been great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to have one Activity be a subcomponent of another activity using Dagger Android?

***tl;dr*** You can't. Dagger Android follows a strict `AppComponent > ActivityComponent > FragmentComponent` scheme and there is no way to add custom scopes in-between.

---

I suggest you have a look at the Dagger Android source code, it's really not that much. It's basicalle a HashMap for each layer where you look up the component builder and build the subcomponent. A fragment looks at its parent Activity, an Activity looks at the Application. There is no feature where you can add custom components between layers.

What you *can* do is create your own variant of "Dagger Android" where you can implement your own interfaces and mix/match components as you need them. But that's quite a bit of extra work. I created a [`@PerScreen` scope that survives configuration changes](https://gist.github.com/bleeding182/3de7151949090f5f0e33b6cd7ca37cf4) as a proof of concept if you are interested to see how you could do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you don't mind me asking a follow-up question here, how should I do to achieve the goal that the same instance of a class is shared only among Activity B, C, and D but no A (the @UserScope example)?

Comment: It's not doable with the `AndroidInjection` provided by Dagger. Check the gist that I linked. Instead of persisting the component per activity you have to persist it while the user is logged in. Then you then have to find a way to instantiate the subcomponent either from your userComponent or appComponent, depending on which activity. I'm sure it's doable, but you should be sure to understand how Dagger works or it will be a tedious task. There is a lot of guides on how to do user scopes, you can also follow those.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Scope called for example `@PerScreen`, also you will have `@PerActvity` scope. The difference between these scopes is that the `@PerActivity` scope will maintain shared dependencies between all activities like `Context`, Layout Inflater, etc. And all activity specific dependencies will be scoped as `@PerScreen`.

```
@PerApplication -> @PerActivity -> @PerScreen
```

This could structured like that.
I have explained scopes under the hood in [my blog post](https://crosp.net/blog/software-development/mobile/android/understanding-dagger-2-scopes-under-the-hood/), you can refer to it to get better understanding of this matter.